# LWJGL not rendering textures correctly?

Tags: java, rendering, lwjgl

I use LWJGL to render everything in my game I am making, and I use it to render backgrounds, which is okay, but when I render things less than the full size of the display, it shows random lines and the image is slanted. Here is a screenshot picture;

See the split line about a third of the way across, and the line on the left hand side.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O9dI.png

And here is my code;

```
        ImageLoader.STAT_BAR.bind();

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0); //TOP LEFT
        GL11.glVertex2f(0,0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0); //TOP RIGHT
        GL11.glVertex2f(ImageLoader.STAT_BAR.getTextureWidth(),0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1); //BOTTOM RIGHT
        GL11.glVertex2f(ImageLoader.STAT_BAR.getTextureWidth(), ImageLoader.STAT_BAR.getTextureHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1); //BOTTOM LEFT
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, ImageLoader.STAT_BAR.getTextureHeight());
    GL11.glEnd();
```

PS. ImageLoad is just a class I made that get the images and loads them. It's very simple and works for all the images. It's just the rendering that isn't working.

EDIT: Even when changing GL11.glVertex2f to 2i, it still doesnt work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not absolutely sure what the problem is. I can't seem to reproduce it afterwards, unfortunately. Yet I figured it should be solved by one of the following:

- Unsupported Image Size

OpenGL relies heavily on so images, whose resolution's width and height are powers of 2 (when width/height=n*2). If the images files aren't up to that specification, LWJGL might act oddly. Also, don't worry about the image files being squished. That's dependent on the vertex input, not on the texture input.

- Unsupported Image Extension

Try saving your image files as non-interlaced PNG files. Slick_Util, or whatever you use for loading the image files, might not fully support the images you're giving to it.

- Correction Hints

As a last resort, you could add the following lines of code to your initialization code:

```
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
```

Hopefully one of these tips helps you.

Comment: Thank you! It turned out to be the fact that the image was not a direct power of 2. My image now overlaps the screen, but you cannot tell, and it works fine :D