# Drawn Image In OpenGL Comes Out Wrong Size And With Black Boxes In It

Tags: java, opengl, render, lwjgl

Im currently trying to work on my Java project which includes LWJGL.
I have come so far with my "game" that im now drawing an image to the screen.

The problem im getting is that the drawn image gets drawn with black boxes in it and its not the correct size.
here is an image of how it looks visually.
[image]

Here is how the actualy red square image should look like:

[image]

Here is the code i use for rendering with OpenGL, I cannot figure out what im doing wrong.

```
public class Renderer {

//Integers used for player cordinates, Taken from player class by using Static variables
int playerX;
int playerY;

SpriteSheetLoader spriteLoader;
Texture player;

public Renderer(){

}

public void initRenderer(){
    //Initialize OpenGL
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Resets any previous projection matrices
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

            try {
    player = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/PaddleTemp.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void update(){
    GL11.glClear( GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    playerX = Player.playerX; //Gets player x and y from the player class using static variables
    playerY = Player.playerY;

    player.bind();

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);  //top left
        GL11.glVertex2f(playerX, playerY);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);    //Top right
        GL11.glVertex2f(playerX + 50, playerY);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); //Bottom right
        GL11.glVertex2f(playerX + 50, playerY + 150);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1); //bottom left
        GL11.glVertex2f(playerX, playerY + 150);
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not absolutely sure what the problem is. I can't seem to reproduce it afterwards, unfortunately. Yet I figured it should be solved by one of the following:

- Unsupported Image Size

OpenGL relies heavily on so images, whose resolution's width and height are powers of 2 (when width/height=n*2). If the images files aren't up to that specification, LWJGL might act oddly. Also, don't worry about the image files being squished. That's dependent on the vertex input, not on the texture input.

- Unsupported Image Extension

Try saving your image files as non-interlaced PNG files. Slick_Util, or whatever you use for loading the image files, might not fully support the images you're giving to it.

- Correction Hints

As a last resort, you could add the following lines of code to your initialization code:

```
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
```

Hopefully one of these tips helps you.

Source: [LWJGL not rendering textures correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618802/lwjgl-not-rendering-textures-correctly)

Comment: OpenGL-2 and later doesn't impose constraints on valid image dimensions. Only OpenGL-1.x required either texture image dimension to be a power of 2.

Comment: Strange, but there is 3 different possible solutions in the post and it happends that the one about dimensions solved my problem. But thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: @Rasko: the more likely solution is, that OpenGL's pixel store settings didn't match your image data's layout. OpenGL by default assumes a 4 byte row alignment. Every image with a width larger than 4 and being a power of 2 naturally has this alignment, that's why making texture widths a power of 2 dows hide alignment settings. If I were you I'd try setting `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` right before the call to `glTex[Sub]Image` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I have a really easy fix for you. Your main problem is that you are using an unsupported image size, but OpenGL is good when it just expands the actual size of the sprite to be correct. It also records the exact float value for the width and height of the image so that you can in fact use images that are any size you want. Just replace your current rendering code with this:

```
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);  //top left
    GL11.glVertex2f(playerX, playerY);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(player.getWidth(),0);    //Top right
    GL11.glVertex2f(playerX + 50, playerY);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(player.getWidth(), player.getHeight()); //Bottom right
    GL11.glVertex2f(playerX + 50, playerY + 150);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, player.getHeight()); //bottom left
    GL11.glVertex2f(playerX, playerY + 150);
GL11.glEnd();
```

Also, you can disregard the other answer as this one should be your solution.

Comment: I should also add that with my solution, you can use an image with any dimension you want.

Comment: Thanks but i already solved if by using the other answear, Have an upvote tho!

Comment: Well, just remember that you can use this solution on any image that isn't 2^x in width or height.